# 'Easy' proof for Invariance of Domain for a 2D ball

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, continuity, invariance

In class, **Invariance of Domain** was proved using lots of machinery, but I came up with the following 'proof' whose truth I am suspicious of.

Explicitly statement to prove is :

> Let $B$ = $\{ \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R^2} \hspace{2mm} :  \|\vec{x}\| < 1 \}$ and $f:B \rightarrow f(B) \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ be an injective continuous map with vector outputs (in the plane). Then f is a homeomorphism. $B$ is given the subspace topology.

Alleged proof goes like this:

> Let $B_r = \{ \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R^2} : \|\vec{x}\| \leq r \}$ be any **closed** ball of radius $r<1$ inside $B$. Restriction of $f$ to $B_r$ is injective map from a compact space to Hausdorff space, hence is homeomorphism. In particular, it restricts to a homeo between $O_r = \{ x\in B_r : \|\vec{x} \|<r  \}$ of $B_r$ , which is an $r$-ball in $\mathbb{R^2}$, and its image.
> Notice $r$ was almost arbitrary (apart from having proper size).

(I couldn't connect this two sections into $1$ section. If you could explain how to, please let me know)

> Now take any point $y$ in $f(B)$. We must have $y = f(x)$ for some $x\in B$ and we can choose a small enough neighborhood around $x$ with radius $\epsilon$ so that $f$ on $B_{\| x \| + 2\epsilon}$ is homeomorphism. Thus it sends $\epsilon$ ball around x into another ball around $y$ which lies in $f(B_{\| x \| + 2\epsilon}) \subset f(B)$.

Is there something wrong here? It should not have been this easy.

Comment: What is the codomain of $f$?

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: The mistake is in the last sentence and also in general sloppiness of what the word "open" refers to when discussing various spaces (a subset can be open in the subspace topology but not in topology of the larger space). Ditto the word "interior."

Comment: could you elaborate what is the mistake? I changed the ambigious 'open' term to the which set I mean.